# open file with O_CREAT|O_RDWR will cause the file to be write only

Tags: c, linux

In my c code I write to afile using `open()` with option `O_CREAT|O_RDWR` and then `write()`:

```
    readfd = open("ak.bin", O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
    if (readfd >= 0) {
        res = write(readfd, key, 16);
        close(readfd);
    }
```

after executing my program I found that the file `"ak.bin"` is with write permission only. I can not read it!

```
$ ls -l | grep ak
-----w---- 1 mohamed mohamed     16 Jun  3 18:30 ak.bin
```

What I m missing? I want my file to be readeable also.

Comment: Do you really want to use `open` instead of `fopen`? `open` is a low-level system call function, `fopen` for example support the buffering as some other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify the *mode* when creating (`O_CREAT`) the file.

From man [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> The mode argument specifies the file mode bits be applied when a new
>   file is created.  **This argument must be supplied when O_CREAT or
>   O_TMPFILE is specified in flags**; if neither O_CREAT nor O_TMPFILE is specified, then mode is ignored.  The
>                 effective mode is modified by the process's umask in the usual
>                 way: in the absence of a default ACL, the mode of the created
>                 file is (mode & ~umask).  Note that this mode applies only to
>                 future accesses of the newly created file; the open() call
>                 that creates a read-only file may well return a read/write
>                 file descriptor.

Comment: maybe add `int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);`?